# Is there a way to store & retrieve a window's state in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, savepoints

Currently, we have a  keyed Window flink job that works as expected. Events come into the window - some processing is done in a reduce function - a trigger causes output to a sink.

Now we have a scenario where the volume of events will be scaled up and the length of time the keyed window needs to be kept open goes from a few minutes to hours/days.

While job definitions could be more or less the same as before, additional storage requirements come into play. Also requiring horizontal scaling, such as scale out the task slots, increase the storage, etc.
Is this the recommended approach - i.e., scale out to support the increased volume of events and longer window times?
That somehow feels wasteful since, the longer window times also imply that window remains needlessly open when there are NO events coming into it? Thus, is there a way in Flink to seamlessly move the job state to disk during idle periods and bring it back when fresh events show up in the window? Something like a `savepoint` per window?

Comment: Note that since you're doing a reduce, increasing the volume of events won't directly impact the size of your state. More data would only cause this if it also meant more unique keys for the active windows.

Comment: You didn't mention whether your windows were tumbling or sliding. If tumbling, then increasing the window size won't increase the size of your state. If sliding, then yes, but you could mitigate some of the increase by having a larger slide value, thus reducing the total number of active windows.

Comment: It is a keyed window, that is open for maxTime OR until a trigger condition, whichever is earlier. 
e.g., 
1. 10 events are expected for a given key. Max window length is 3 days. All 10 events show up in the first minute. Thus, window can be purged after that first minute. 
2. Same. However, the 10 events show up over the entire 3 days, say 3 on first day, 3 on second day, etc. Maybe they show up clumped together or widely separated. 

It's for this second use case that the question is posted. The window is mostly idle and retaining state (even if it is small) throughout 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

For windows being processed by a reduce function, the state involved should be just a single object (per key, per window), so hopefully the total volume of state involved won't be outrageous.

You can always use the RocksDB state backend, in which case the state will be kept on disk, with the active state in off-heap memory.

Comment: Thanks David. Please see my response above to kkrugler. 

It's not the volume of the state as much as the volume of events on the stream. 

Does the RocksDB option allow for automatic removal of state in memory to RocksDB when it is "idle" and automatic retrieval back into memory when the next event for that window arrives?

Comment: Looks like this article is related to my query and specific use case - "long windows".
https://flink.apache.org/2021/01/18/using-rocksdb-state-backend-in-apache-flink-when-and-how/

Comment: RocksDB handles all of that automatically. When you use it, you can think of your state as living on disk, with an in-memory cache. I believe it's just what you want.